# Access own Azure internal load balancer from backend server pool

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have set up an internal load balancer (lb1) with one server (srv1) as only VM in the backend pool. When I try to access the loadbalancer lb1 from this server (srv1), I get a timeout. I have a second load balancer setup in the same subnet (lb2 and srv2). All traffic on port 443. Inbound and outbound rules allow traffic on all ports to/from subnet.

srv1 can access lb2 but not lb1

srv2 can access lb1 but not lb2

Is this by design, or have I missed a configuration option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this by design, or have I missed a configuration option?

This is a by design behavior. The load balancer is used for redistributing the request to the VMs in the backend pool. The VM in the pool can not access the load balancer in the same pool.

Comment: I contacted MS Support, and they comfirm that "This behavior is by design  – The VM sees the destination and the source is the same and drops the packet for security reasons."

Comment: Do we know if this is still the case in 2023? Would a public load balancer be the only way around this?

Comment: @Edgaras are you using windows servers? If that's the case, this will work for you:: https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-ILB-hairpin . Unfortunately I still can't find way to make Linux work.